# JQuery show div if field value < n and NOT empty

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, html

I am trying to work out how to show a div based on input to a field. I want to show the div if both of these conditions are true:

1) the field value is <=30
2) the field is not empty

at the moment i i have figured out the <=30 bit but then the form assumes that empty is 0 and shows the div, but i dont want the div to show if the field is left blank.

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
 $("#hidden")[$(this).val() <= "30" and !="" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
```

Here's what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/q5kKz/318/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: jQuery 1.4.1 ? Really ?

Answer (score 3):

Fix the syntax :

```
 var val = this.value;
 $("#hidden")[(val !=='' && val <= 30) ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/SFAX5/) (I fixed a few other problems)

Comment: @roasted Damn... I usually fix those ones immediately !

Comment: Hi dystroy thanks thats a big help. any way to delay show of second textbox by say 1 second, otherwise if a user enters 31, the hidden field will open and quickly close again (because for a moment it looks like they entered 3)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is tha 30 is a string so you need to cast it to int, like this

```
$("#hidden")[parseInt($(this).val()) <= 30 && !="" ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
```

hope it will work for you!

Comment: `and` is not the proper syntax for a second argument..it's `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/q5kKz/322/

use `&&` not `and`

```
$('#Severity-of-your-symptoms').change(function() {
  $("#li-10-14")[this.value <= "30" && this.value != '' ? 'show' : 'hide']("fast");
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

http://jsfiddle.net/q5kKz/323/

this "===" is important in string comparison :

```
$(this).val() !== "" && $(this).val()*1 <= 30
```

You should also consider using other events like keypress or the JS will only trigger when it loses the focus.